# In My existing Project I have used componentWillMount(). Now its deprecated. So what should i do?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, containers

Reajctjs official doc is saying componentWillMount() is deprecated.its unsafe to use. so in my current live project i have used this in many container. is there any chances it will[image] break my live system in production?please advise,Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

> This lifecycle was previously named `componentWillMount`. That name will continue to work **until version 17**.

You can transform your files before that either manually or by using [react-codemod](https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod#rename-unsafe-lifecycles)